# Difference between yield and yield* in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to know what's the difference between this two. I find this SO post on javascript, [Delegated yield (yield star, yield *) in generator functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491779/delegated-yield-yield-star-yield-in-generator-functions)

From what I understand, `yield*` delegates to the another generator and after the another generator stop producing values, then it resumes generating its own values.

Explanation and examples on the dart side would be helpful.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

#### `yield`

It is used to emit values from a generator either async or sync.

**Example:**

```
Stream<int> getStream(int n) async* {
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    yield i;
  }
}

void main() {
  getStream(3).forEach(print);
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
```

---

#### `yield*`

It delegates the call to another generator and after that generator stops producing the values, it resumes generating its own values.

**Example:**

```
Stream<int> getStream(int n) async* {
  if (n > 0) {  
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    yield n; 
    yield* getStream(n - 1); 
  }
}

void main() {
  getStream(3).forEach(print);
}
```

**Output:**

```
3
2 
1
```

Comment: What would happen if I would use `yield numbersDownFrom(n - 1)` instead of `yield* numbersDownFrom(n - 1);` inside of the generator ?

Comment: @sonic `yield*` is used to delegate the call to the generator, `yield numbersDownFrom(n-1)` won't make any sense because `yield` only yields the type you wanted to return in your `Stream`.

Comment: I need to test it on my own. I was just curious if it will be flagged as error or it will do something unexpected. Thanks for answer.

Comment: There's an error in the beginning of the answer:the sentence  'It is used to emit values from a generator either async or sync.' should be 'It is used to emit values from a generator either async* or sync*.' See https://jelenaaa.medium.com/what-are-sync-async-yield-and-yield-in-dart-defe57d06381

Answer (score 63):

### Short answer

- `yield` provides a single value in an Iterable or a Stream.
- `yield*` provides multiple values from another Iterable or Stream.

### Iterable (synchronous) example

Take a look at how the following two iterables interact:

```dart
void main() {
  final myIterable = getValues();
  for (int value in myIterable) {
    print(value);
  }
}

Iterable<int> getValues() sync* {
  yield 42;
  yield* getThree();
  yield* [6, 7, 8];
  yield 24;
}

Iterable<int> getThree() sync* {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}
```

Here's what's happening:

- `sync*` creates an iterable, making it a [synchronous generator function](https://dart.dev/language/functions#generators).
- `yield 42` provides a single value (42) for the `getValues` generator function.
- `yield*` provides multiple values for `getValues` by requesting all of the iterable values from the `getThree` generator function.
- Since a list is also iterable, `yield* [6, 7, 8]` yields each of the values in the list for `getValues`.
- Finally, `yield 24` provides another single value for `getValues`. This value is only provided after the previous `yield*` calls to the other iterables have completed.

Run the code above, and you'll see the following result:

```
42
1
2
3
6
7
8
24
```

### Stream (asynchronous) example

Now have a look at the stream version:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  final myStream = getValues();
  await for (int value in myStream) {
    print(value);
  }
}

Stream<int> getValues() async* {
  yield 42;
  yield* getThree();
  yield* Stream.fromIterable([6, 7, 8]);
  yield 24;
}

Stream<int> getThree() async* {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}
```

Notes:

- `async*` creates a stream, making it an [asynchronous generator function](https://dart.dev/language/functions#generators).
- As before, `yield` provides a single value.
- `yield*` provides multiple values from another stream.
- `yield*` waits for the called stream to complete before going on.

Run that, and again you'll see the following output:

```
42
1
2
3
6
7
8
24
```

*This answer is a complete rewrite of my original answer (see edit history), where I had grossly misunderstood the meaning of `yield*`, even after watching the [Generator Functions - Flutter in Focus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TF-TBsgIErY&list=PLjxrf2q8roU2HdJQDjJzOeO6J3FoFLWr2&index=19&t=0s) video. Thanks to [@Hackmodford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758083/hackmodford) for correcting me in the comments.*

Comment: `yield*` is not related to recursion. Your example just happens to use recursion. It can also yield to different streams.

Comment: @Hackmodford, please explain more. I pulled the recursive part from the [Flutter team video](https://youtu.be/TF-TBsgIErY?list=PLjxrf2q8roU2HdJQDjJzOeO6J3FoFLWr2&t=274). I still don't understand it well though, especially if it isn't about recursion.

Comment: It's just going to `yield*` the stream until it's done and then continue execution. So let's say you're writing a async* generator. You can `yield` values A, then B, then `yield*` an entirely different stream (say it emits C, and D, then finishes), then you could `yield` E, F, and finish.

The output would be A,B,C,D,E,F and the C,D came from a different stream that only emits those values.

Recursion not really related.

Comment: @Hackmodford, That helps a lot. Thank you. I think I understand now. I've rewritten my answer, so if you have a chance, take a look and see if I have any more mistakes.

Comment: Yup! This is my understanding of how it works. I have updated my vote.

Comment: @Suragch Great answer, except for the fact that both examples have the same exact behavior in the end, so this is not super helpful in understanding the differences. Is the only difference that `Iterable` is forced to be end-to-end synchronous, whereas `Stream` is asynchronous, so you need a way to syntactically indicate whether you're dealing with synchronous or asynchronous generation? (Although even then, there is no syntactic difference between `yield*` for the synchronous vs. asynchronous case, so the need for different syntax in the other cases doesn't make sense.)

Comment: (...continued...) -- Maybe start by showing how `await` can be used in the `async*` case but not the `sync*` case. I assume therefore that `yield*` can only be used with `sync*` generators, if the surrounding function is a `sync*` generator, whereas `yield*` can be used with `async*` or `sync*` generators, from within an `async*` generator. One other thing that could be pointed out then is that `*` just means `generator`, nothing more than that, and the only reason that `sync*` needs to be explicitly spelled out is that adding only `*` after a function wouldn't be good syntax.

Comment: @Suragch I wrote all this up in my own answer, check it out.

Comment: @LukeHutchison, I'm glad you were able to find the answers. I wasn't focusing on the difference between iterables and streams here, so it's good to have your answer for other people with the same questions. +1

Answer (score 5):

I have created a [dart pad](https://dartpad.dev/53d30c4fab2c168bcea5a36914262295) link to help people experiment:

Yield* is used to yield a whole iterable one value at a time with out using a loop.

These 2 functions do exactly the same thing, generates an iterable based on the start and finish values.

```
Iterable<int> getRangeIteration(int start, int finish) sync* {
  for(int i = start; i<= finish; i++){
  yield i;
  }
}

Iterable<int> getRangeRecursive(int start, int finish) sync* {
  if (start <= finish) {
    yield start;
    yield* getRangeRecursive(start + 1, finish);
  }
}
```

In the first implementation (yield i) would imply type Iterable which matches the function's return type.

now if in the second implementation instead of

```
 yield* getRangeRecursive(start + 1, finish);
```

if we did

```
yield getRangeRecursive(start + 1, finish);
```

we will get a compiler error:

```
The type 'Iterable<Iterable<int>>' implied by the 'yield' expression must be assignable to 'Iterable<int>'.
```

as you can see the yield wraps the Iterable with another Iterable<>, which makes the type Iterable<Iterable>. Which does not match the return type of the function.

If we have to do recursion without using yield* we will have to do this:

```
Iterable<int> getRangeRecursiveWithOutYieldStar(int start, int finish) sync* {
  if (start <= finish) {
    yield start;
    for (final val in getRangeRecursiveWithOutYieldStar(start + 1, finish)){
    yield val;
    }
  }
}
```

Which is messy and inefficient.

So I feel like in my opinion yield* flattens another generator function.

A few good resources:
[Generator Functions - Flutter in Focus video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TF-TBsgIErY)

Medium article:
[What are sync*, async*, yield and yield* in Dart?](https://jelenaaa.medium.com/what-are-sync-async-yield-and-yield-in-dart-defe57d06381)

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to figure this out, but this is my current understanding:

### The meaning of `*`

`*` just means "generator". So:

- `sync*` is a synchronous generator function (a function which can `yield` values but can't `await` a function call to an async function). `sync*` functions have type `Iterable<T>`.
- `async*` is an asynchronous generator function (a function that can `yield` values, including after `await`ing the result of a function call to another `async` function). `async*` functions have type `Stream<T>`, which conceptually sort of like an "async iterable", although `Stream` has a different API than `Iterable`, as described below.

A generator function (a function that can `yield` values) basically has its execution state frozen in place after each value is `yield`ed, and no more code is executed in the generator function until the next value is requested by the caller. This continues until the generator function returns, at which time the caller is informed that there are no more values available.

### `for` is used with `Iterable` (`sync*`), `await for` is used with `Stream` (`async*`)

Given

- `Iterable<T> syncIterable() sync* {...}` and
- `Stream<T> asyncStream() async* {...}` ,

if you want to iterate over the results yielded by these generator functions:

- For `sync*` generator functions, you have to use `for (var x in syncIterable)`.
- For `async*` generator functions, you have to use `await for (var y in asyncStream)`.

You get an error if you try to use the wrong type of generator:

- If you try to use `for (var x in asyncStream)`, then you will get the error: `The type Stream<T> used in the 'for' loop must implement 'Iterable'`. The purpose of this is to disallow synchronous code from calling asynchronous code. Synchronous code cannot cross an async gap.
- `await for (var x in syncIterable)`, then you will get the error: `The type Iterable<T> used in the 'for' loop must implement 'Stream'`. Async code can always call synchronous code, but the purpose of this is to highlight the fact that synchronous generators do not *conceptually* wrap the value-yielding code in a `Future<T>` (so this is a type error).

### The distinction between `Iterable` and `Stream`

There are other ways to deal with `Iterable` and `Stream` other than `for`  and `await for`, e.g. for `Iterable`, you can call `syncIterable.iterator` to get an `Iterator`, followed by calls to `current` and `moveNext()` to deal with the values one at a time rather than in a `for` loop.

However, `Stream` doesn't include a `.iterator` getter, because the `Iterator` API is synchronous, and `Stream` is asynchronous. Providing `.iterator` would allow synchronous code to call `async` code without `await`ing it. There is simply no way to wrap an async API (here `Stream`) in a synchronous wrapper (here `Iterator`). Again, it is impossible for sync code to cross an async gap.

### The meaning of `yield*`

Now consider `yield*`. Again `*` just means "generator". In this case, this syntax means "yield all values in the following generator, in order, before proceeding". It is a way to defer to another generator.

- If `yield*` is used within a `sync*` function, it implements `for (var x in syncIterator) { yield x; }`.
- If `yield*` is used within an `async*` function, it implements `await for (var y in asyncStream) { yield y; }`.

This of course has to work differently for the sync and async cases, but the syntax in this case is exactly the same -- there is no syntactic distinction in the use of `yield*` in sync vs. async contexts, like there is between `for` and `await for`. The semantics of the `yield*` syntax are context-dependent! (This is surprising to me, I would expect `await yield*` for the async case, for consistency with `await for`, but this is not what the Dart language designers went with.)

You do get an error if you try to use `yield*` with the wrong type of generator:

- If you try to call `yield* asyncStream` from within a `sync*` function, you will get `The type 'Stream<T>' implied by the 'yield*' expression must be assignable to 'Iterable<T>'`.
- If you try to call `yield* syncIterable` from within an `async*` function, you will get `The type 'Iterable<T>' implied by the 'yield*' expression must be assignable to 'Stream<T>'`.

Answer (score -1):

Use the code below to understand why coding recursion without using yield* is really inefficient.

```
Iterable<int> getRangeYield(int start, int end) sync* {
  if (start <= end) {
    yield start;
    for (final int val in getRangeYield(start + 1, end)) {
      yield val;
    }
  }
}

Iterable<int> getRangeYieldAnalysed(int start, int end) sync* {
  if (start <= end) {
    print('before start $start');
    yield start * 10;
    print('after start $start');
    for (final int val in getRangeYieldAnalysed(start + 1, end)) {
      print('before val $val');
      yield val * 100;
      print('after val $val');
    }
  }
}

Iterable<int> getRangeYieldStar(int start, int end) sync* {
  // same output as getRangeYield()
  if (start < end) {
    yield* getRangeYieldStar(start + 1, end);
  }
  yield start;
}

Iterable<int> getRangeYieldStarAnalysed(int start, int end) sync* {
  // same output as getRangeYield()
  print('generator $start started');
  if (start < end) {
    yield* getRangeYieldStarAnalysed(start + 1, end);
  }
  yield start;
  print('generator $start ended');
}

Iterable<int> getRangeForLoop(int start, int end) sync* {
  // same output as getRangeYield()
  for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    yield i;
  }
}

void main() {
  Iterable<int> it = getRangeYieldStarAnalysed(1, 4);
  print('main range obtained');

  for(int element in it) {
    print('el $element');
  };
}
```