# How can "yield*" improves generator performance?

Tags: dart

I saw on the Dart documentation ([Link](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generators)) that **yield*** improves the performance of a recursive generator.

```
Iterable<int> naturalsDownFrom(int n) sync* {
    if (n > 0) {
        yield n;
        yield* naturalsDownFrom(n - 1);
    }
}
```

I don't get how that can be

Or how does the **yield*** works. What the differences between **yield** and **yield*** ?

Comment: Can you refer us to the documentation that claims it improves performance? In the example you give, it seems like if you substituted `yield*` for `yield`, it would simply fail type checking; `n` is an expression of type `int`, and `naturalsDownFrom(n-1)` is of type `Iterable<int>`. Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57492517/difference-between-yield-and-yield-in-dart) for an explanation of the difference between the two forms.

Comment: Do you mean, using `yield*`, versus `yield`ing from a loop from `n` to `0` inside the generator?

Comment: @Noah I think that it wouldn't fail (Based  on my exprience in other similar languages, so don't know if things are not the same in Dart) cause the supplied expression for `yield*` must be an Iterable of the same type of the generated value (Or a Stream if the function was defined using async). 
I add the link on the post. And the example is from the documentation also.

Comment: Right, the docs are contrasting this example, where you `yield*` a new generator, with the one above it, where you `yield` the next value from inside a loop inside the same generator. In the `yield` example, when the generator resumes, it has to reload its state — its variables' values and so on — which is relatively costly. The `yield*` example doesn't have that problem. Yet they both generate the same sequence of values. This is an optimization similar to (or maybe the same as) [tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion).

Comment: Thnaks @Noah. Yes it's the same as tail recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't argue that you should use `yield*` for *performance*.

You should use `yield*` whenever you want to emit all the events of another stream inside an `async*` function.

The `yield*` differs from `yield` in that the latter emits a single value, and the former emits all the events of another stream.

Doing

```dart
yield* someStream;
```

is *almost* the same as doing:

```dart
await for (var value in someStream) {
  yield value;
}
```

That is, the `yield*` emits the same data events as the stream it works on.

The difference is that `yield*` also emits error events, and always emits the entire stream, where the `await for` stops at the first error event.

You should *not* make your function recursive unless necessary, just to use `yield*`, that's not going to help performance.