# How to test exceptions thrown from an async generator?

Tags: flutter, exception, dart, stream

I have a [repository](https://deviq.com/repository-pattern/) class in my Flutter app with the following method that returns a Stream:

```dart
Stream<List<Product>> getProducts() async* {
  var currentUser = await this._auth.currentUser();

  if (currentUser == null) {
    throw AuthException('not_logged_in',
        'No current user found probably because user is not logged in.');
  }

  yield* ...
}
```

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54756614/1775160) on SO, the above way to throw an exception from an async generator function looks fine.

How do I write my test (with [test](https://pub.dev/packages/test) package) so to test the exception thrown by this method?

Something like this **does not work**:

```dart
test('should throw exception when user is not logged in', () {
  final _authSignedOut = MockFirebaseAuth(signedIn: false);
  final _repoWihoutUser = FirebaseProductRepository(
    storeInstance: _store,
    authInstance: _authSignedOut,
  );

  var products = _repoWihoutUser.getProducts();

  expect(products, emitsError(AuthException));
});
```

Nor this:

```dart
expect(callback, emitsError(throwsA(predicate((e) => e is AuthException))));
```

Not even this:

```dart
var callback = () {
  _repoWihoutUser.getProducts();
};

expect(callback, emitsError(throwsA(predicate((e) => e is AuthException))));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close.  Your first attempt:

```dart
expect(products, emitsError(AuthException));
```

doesn't work because [`emitsError`](https://pub.dev/documentation/test_api/latest/test_api/emitsError.html) takes a `Matcher` as its argument, so you can't pass it a type directly.  Instead, you need to use the [`isA<T>()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/matcher/latest/matcher/isA.html) `Matcher`:

```dart
expect(products, emitsError(isA<AuthException>()));
```